# Simulate Mouse in Python doesn't work (Windows)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am quite the beginner and have the folloing problem: I am trying to automate a mouse movement and some key presses and the code works until I select the program window. (So I can run it and use it for every program I tried except the one I want to use it for). The code still runs but the mouse movement it should do does simply not happen and I don't know why.

I have tried it using `win32api, win32con` and `pyautogui` both failed. So is there any possibility to make the mouse movements more like real mouse movements? or does anyone have an idea why it might not work?

```
   def click(x,y):
       win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
       win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,x,y,0,0)
       win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,x,y,0,0)
   click(x, y)
```

and

```
   pyautogui.click(x, y)
```

Comment: Please provide a code example.

Comment: What is the "one program you want to use this for"? My educated guess is it's running with different privileges than your mouse simulator.

Comment: @AKX It is a game where i want to skip some grinding and it has admin privileges, so if your assumtion is right, ist there any way to change the privileges of my program?

Comment: You could run your script as administrator and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments:

As the target application is running with administrator privileges, a nonprivileged program can't simulate events on it.

To work around that, run your script as administrator.